# How do I add autocompletions to functions in Node.js Modules?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a module in node.js and I want to create a function with autocompletions for string input.
example:
[image: example]

I have not found any docs for this.

Comment: Have you tried [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/)?

Comment: Well, I haven't even heard about it before.